# How to instantiate a class from a external gem in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I instantiate a class inside my controller from a external gem in Ruby?

Example: I put on my Gemfile this gem. https://github.com/sportdb/sport.db/tree/master/sportdb-models/lib/sportdb/models

And I want to put on my controller, for example, a `Team` from the model.

https://github.com/sportdb/sport.db/blob/master/sportdb-models/lib/sportdb/models/team.rb

If i try to do like this:

```
def index
  @foo = Team.first
end
```

This message is outputed:

> uninitialized constant Team

So, what is the right way of instantiate this class *team.rb* on my controller?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `SportDB::Model::Team.new`?

Answer (score 0):

In ruby you can put modules and classes inside a **namespace**. A namespace can help to organize classes into logical groups and avoid collision. For example when you use a gem that provides a class with a common name (like `Team`) that could clash with your own classes or with classes from another gem.

The `Team` class is inside the module `Model`, which in turn is inside the module `SprtDb`. So the full class name that you should use is: `SportDb::Model::Team` and not just `Team`